# SQL Server : find index of string

Tags: sql-server, indexing

`User` table

```
 UserId   UserName
   55     FirstUser
   22     SecondUser
    5     ThirdUser
   33     FourthUser
```

I have a username "SecondUser".

I want to match "SecondUser" name with the `UserName` column, after that I want to get it's `index`.

How can I find the `index` of `SecondUser` in SQL Server?

Any help will be appreciated with points.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're asking what I think you're asking, there's (in standard SQL) no "index" to be had. If you're not ordering by something (like UserId or UserName), the table can be in one order when you first select it, and in an entirely different order the next time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**[Here is the SQLFiddel Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b4e2/2)**

**Below is the Sample Query :**

```
select *,
       row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as 'Index'
  from [user]
```

Note : This answer is applicable only if there is no `Clustered Index` or `Primary Key` in `[user]` table. If there is `Primary Key` or `Clustered Index` in your table on any column then while querying `Select * from [user]` will give the output with Sorted rows on the primary key column or a column on which clustered index is formed.

Comment: Of course, since your `order by` values are the same for every row, there's still no guarantee that the same rows will be assigned the same values each time this query executes.

Comment: @user2869820 - we're trying to tell you (and Romesh) that this is essentially a random number generator - it may give you the answer 2 today, the answer 4 tomorrow, etc. For whatever reason you need this "index", it's almost certainly *unsuitable* for that purpose.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : I think OP needed rownumber instead of index. I just provided that. I think OP has misunderstood the term Index with rownum.

Comment: I think Damien is jeaolous :)

Comment: @user2869820 : No, He is not. But he is clearing the concept of word 'Index' in `SQL-Server`

Comment: FYI, the downvote on this question was done by me and in [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fda3b/1) you should be able to see why.

Comment: @user2869820 - I didn't downvote. But you've got (at least) 3 people telling you that there's no ordering of rows in a table that you can rely on, and in addition that this answer doesn't provide a *stable* result which you can do anything with. Do you think we're all lying?

Comment: @user2869820 : I have modified my post check and confirm that Is it applicable for you. If it still applicable to you then I think you should change the title from Index to RowNumber

Comment: "`Select * from [user]` will give the output with Sorted rows on the primary key column" - it may, it may not. That's what we're all trying to tell user2869820 and yourself - there are **no** ordering guarantees provided by SQL Server in this case. The only way to get a well defined order is to provide an `ORDER BY` clause with sufficient specificity such that each row has a unique value for those columns.

Comment: Yes, Agree with u. But this is also fact that, if there is no Primary Key or Clustered index defined then the way or sequence in which data has inserted is retrieved while select query. And thats what OP is getting as un-ordered record. But now he want a rownumber for each row and not index which he has mentioned in his title.

Comment: [Here is a SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29ed9/1) with no Primary Key and no Clustered Key that still does not get the expected order of rows.

Comment: Ok.. @MikaelEriksson thanx for clearing my missing point of Nonclustered index. That means now, OP is not having any index on the table and wants rownum. :)

Comment: And that will still not work if he is using SQL Server Enterprise edition and the rows are returned using "merry-go-round scanning". Have a look at [Advanced Scanning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191475.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Your question makes no sense .... what do you mean by *index* ??? You can fetch the `UserId` associated with your user name. But what do you mean by *index* ? What would the index of `SecondUser` be in your case??

**Update:** OK - so you want to have some ordering. But you want your data **ordered by what criteria** ?? You need some kind of a column - an `ID`, a `DateTime` column - **SOMETHING** that you can use in an  `ORDER BY` clause.

SQL Server doesn't have any *implicit* ordering per se; if you want to have any **ordering** (and thus an "index" in that order), you **must provide** some kind of column(s) to order by.

If you do have an `ID` column - you could do something like this:

```
;WITH BaseData AS
(
    SELECT 
        [UserId],
        [Index] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID),
        UserName 
    FROM dbo.[User]
)
SELECT *
FROM BaseData
WHERE UserName = 'SecondUser'
```

Comment: yes but syntax error for "index". What to write instead of "index" ?

Comment: @user2869820: you picked a really bad name for a column - of course, `INDEX` is a reserved (key) word in SQL Server - you'll need to put it in square brackets (or pick a more suitable name!) - and `User` btw is also a reserved word in T-SQL ....

Comment: I tried your code , it does not show me which index is. SecondUser must be (2).row according to my list.

Comment: @user2869820: Again: You have misconception here. Rows in SQL tables do not have a particular stable order. They are not guaranteed to be sorted by the order you inserted them. You apply an order explicitly in a `SELECT`...`ORDER BY` statement. If you absolutely want to have something like an index, you must add an `IDENTITY` column that issues consecutive values when a row is inserted.